# create trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, triggers

I have a table named daire, it has columns named Kiraci, D_ID, Sahip. D_ID is PK column. what i want is when i change Kiraci value, i want trigger to delete a row or insert a new row to another table. I tried to create a trigger like written bottom:

```
CREATE TRIGGER daireBosalt AFTER UPDATE ON daire
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Kiraci IS NULL THEN
    DELETE FROM kontrat WHERE kontrat.D_ID = NEW.D_id;
ELSEIF NEW.Kiraci IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO kontrat (D_ID, BAy, BGun, BYil, Tutar, Sahip, Sure, Depo, Komisyon) VALUES (NEW.D_id, '01', '01','2014','100', NEW.Sahip,'1','100','100')
END IF;
END;
```

When i try to create this script, it keeps give me syntax error.

Comment: Did you change the Delimiter? I.e. `DELIMITER \\` before the statement, end the create with `\\` and reset the Delimiter with `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: You are missing the semicolon after your INSERT.

Comment: omg yes right thnx :)

Comment: Just as a matter of logic - why do you feel the need to perform a second test using `ELSEIF` rather than just using `ELSE`? Are you working on a quantum computer where `NEW.Kiraci IS NULL` can be false and yet `New.Kiraci IS NOT NULL` will not be true?

Answer (score 1):

Change the delimiter while you create the trigger:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER daireBosalt AFTER UPDATE ON daire
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Kiraci IS NULL THEN
    DELETE FROM kontrat WHERE kontrat.D_ID = NEW.D_id;
ELSEIF NEW.Kiraci IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO kontrat (D_ID, BAy, BGun, BYil, Tutar, Sahip, Sure, Depo, Komisyon) VALUES (NEW.D_id, '01', '01','2014','100', NEW.Sahip,'1','100','100')
END IF;
END $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: The code you posted does not change the delimiter correctly. If you have a syntax error message you should post it in its entirety.

Comment: 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: CREATE TRIGGER daireBosalt AFTER UPDATE ON daire FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.Kiraci IS NULL THEN DELETE FROM kontrat WHERE kontrat...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
END' at line 8

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.022 sec

This is the error i get